# PostgreSQL ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE

Tags: postgresql

He tratado de implementar ésta formula:

```
CASE WHEN T."Net Changes" <> '0.00' THEN unnest(array['Net Changes',"Ending Release Reason Type"]) ELSE T."Ending Release Reason Type" END "Ending Reason Type Final" from T
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in CASE
>       LINE 2: CASE WHEN T."Net Changes" <> '0.00' THEN unnest(array['Net C...
>                                                    ^
>       HINT:  You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.

Comment: Bienvenido Daniel Orjuela a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. En principio lo que veo es que estás usando un `unnest`  dentro de  un `CASE .. THEN` algo que no es posible hacer. `unnest`  retorna básicamente una tabla y el `THEN` debería retornar un solo elemento escalar.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio por tus sugerencias!!, tienes alguna sugerencia de como usar este tipo de funcion ya que en versiones anteriores si se podia ejecutar de esta forma, estuve leyendo algo sobre LATERAL join pero no lo tengo muy claro, !Gracias por tu Ayuda!.

Comment: No tengo del todo claro el funcionamiento de `postgresql`, lo que si puedo decirte es que `unnest` entiendo retorna una salida tipo tabla, por lo que deberías usarla por ejemplo dentro de un `FROM` o en un `INNER/LEFT/etc JOIN`, no como parte de una columna. Saludos

Comment: En este contexto: http://rextester.com/VJA80370 sí se puede poner un unnest en un case (o sea dentro de un select). Para poder ayudarte mejor sería bueno que nos muestres un poco más de contexto o un ejemplo (como el link que pongo en este post). Suerte